# Entity Framework - Casting the retrieved Combobox value to string

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework, I have a Combobox showing a list of data retrieved from a database.

```
using System;  //I removed the other using statements here to preserve space

namespace ExTea_BackEnd
{
    public partial class frmAddBreakdown : Form
    {
        ExTeaEntities Breakdowns;
        Breakdown_Type BreakdownTypes;

        public frmAddBreakdown()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmbBreakdownType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Breakdown_Type breakdownType = (Breakdown_Type)cmbBreakdownType.SelectedItem;
            string selectedBreakdownTypeId = breakdownType.BrkdwnId;

            IQueryable<Breakdown_Type> breakdownTypeQuery = from t in Breakdowns.Breakdown_Types
                                                            where t.BrkdwnId == selectedBreakdownTypeId
                                                            select t;
            List<Breakdown_Type> selectedBreakdownId = breakdownTypeQuery.ToList();

            if (selectedBreakdownId != null && selectedBreakdownId.Count > 0)
            {
                BreakdownTypes = selectedBreakdownId.First();
                txtBreakdownId.Text = BreakdownTypes.BrkdwnId.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                BreakdownTypes = null;
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Breakdown newBreakdown = new Breakdown();

                Breakdown_Type breakdownType = (Breakdown_Type)cmbBreakdownType.SelectedItem;
                newBreakdown.BrkdwnType = breakdownType.ToString();   //this is where the error occurs

                newBreakdown.MachineId = txtMachineId.Text.Trim();
                newBreakdown.MachineType = txtMachineType.Text.Trim();
                newBreakdown.ReportedDate = dtpDate.Value;
                newBreakdown.JobStatus = "I";

                Breakdowns.AddToBreakdowns(newBreakdown);
                int rowsAffected = Breakdowns.SaveChanges();
                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected + " records added!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured! " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to save the data in the form back to the database, an error occurs when trying to cast the value selected from the Combobox. Even when I've casted it to the right type, it does not save the selected value! But this,

[image]

I'm clueless on what I'm doing wrong here? Can anyone please tell me how to correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newBreakdown.BrkdwnType = breakdownType.ToString();
```

Here you are just calling `.ToString()` Method of your object, so it is returning the Type Name, which you are able to view in database table record, for getting the BrkDwnType Property value you should change statement to

```
newBreakdown.BrkdwnType = breakdownType.BrkdwnType;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the correct answer and the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

it should just be:

```
            newBreakdown.BrkdwnType = cmbBreakdownType.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

no need for casting selectedItem if you just want the string value. From a design point of view, you should probably  normalize your database and use an ID for breakDownType that references another table with BreakDown types.